# Duplicate interface definition and expected selector errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, header-files

I have been working on an iPhone app and came across 2 errors today and was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of fixing them. firstly, I have the code below in ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CIAViewController : UIViewController {
//duplicate interface definition for class 'CIAViewController'
    IBOutlet UILabel *cruzia;
    IBOutlet UILabel *textarea;
    IBOutlet UIButton *playbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *tutorialbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *optionsbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *trainingbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *back;
}

-(IBAction)press;
-(IBAction)press2;
-(IBAction)press3;
-(IBAction)press4;
-(IBAction)press5;
```

I have checked the entire project and cannot seem to find any reference to the interface definition yet I am only a beginner with programming and may have missed something.

The other error is in ViewController.m.

The contents of the file is quite simple:

```
#import "CIAViewController.h"

@interface CIAViewController ()
@end
//Expected selector for Objective-C method

@implementation CIAViewController

-(IBAction)press {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    cruzia.text = @"Play";
    textarea.text = @"Hello! You are playing the game of Cruzia!";
}

-(IBAction)press2 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    cruzia.text = @"Tutorial";
    textarea.text = @"Welcome! You are watching the Cruzia tutorial!";
}

-(IBAction)press3 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    cruzia.text = @"Options";
    textarea.text = @"You are now in the Options screen. You can edit the settings of the game!";
}

-(IBAction)press4 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    cruzia.text = @"Training";
    textarea.text = @"This is the training area. You can improve your Cruzia skills here!";
}

-(IBAction)press5 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 0;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 0;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 0;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 0;
    back.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Cruzia";
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    textarea.hidden = 1;
    playbtn.hidden = 0;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 0;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 0;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 0;
    back.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Cruzia";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

I cannot work out why I am getting this error (expected selector for Objective-C method) and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, If you have time there is a slight problem in my IOS simulator. Whenever I send my project to the simulator it turns out with half the buttons working and the other half working but without text. Any help toward fixing this would be great.

Thanks again,
-George

Comment: Put error message as it

Comment: Check whether your .h file is included in your app's target (it should not be, only the .m file should be). And do a search for `CIAViewController.h` and also `CIAViewController.m`. Sometimes I accidentally `#import` the .m file instead of the .h file.

Comment: @Tarek I am sorry to sound so confused but do you mean I shouldn't have the #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> in my Viewcontroller.h??

Comment: oh, are you missing a `@end` in your CIAViewController.h file, or did you just not paste it in?

Comment: Thanks @esker that solves one of my problems!

Comment: Did it not fix both of the errors mentioned here? Try a clean build.

Comment: No the other error disappeared when I ran the app so thanks that is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

A missing `@end` at the end of the CIAViewController.h header file will cause these sorts of errors. When Xcode attempts to compile your CIAViewController.m file, it sees the `#import "CIAViewController.h"` directive, and basically inserts the code from that header file into the top of your .m file. Thus you have this:

```
@interface CIAViewController : UIViewController {
    ....
}
- (IBAction)variousSelectorsHere;
@interface CIAViewController ()
@end
@implementation CIAViewController
...
```

In these sorts of situations the compiler gets really confused because it can't tell where your original `@interface` declaration ends. As a rule of thumb, if you get errors in a header file about missing class names or other things that don't make sense, look for missing braces or `@end` keywords in the header file or look for header files being incorrectly imported.

This is sort of similar to what happens in C and C++ if you don't have [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).